# Требуется помощь в написании sql-запроса

Tags: sql

Имеется 3 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE Factory
(
Factory_Code char(4) not null unique,
Factory_Desc varchar(100) not null unique,
Type int default 1,
CONSTRAINT pk_FactoryID PRIMARY KEY(Factory_Code)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Volume
(
Year year(4),
Factory_Code char(4) not null unique,
Month month(2),
Product char(8) not null,
Volume double,
CONSTRAINT pk_VolumeID PRIMARY KEY (Year, Factory_Code, Month, Product),
CONSTRAINT fk_ Factory_Code FOREIGN KEY (Factory_Code)
REFERENCES Factory (Factory_Code)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Cost
(
Year year(4),
Factory_Code char(4) not null,
Month month(2),
Product char(8) not null,
Cost_Type int,
Cost double,
LastUpdated datetime default (getdate()),
CONSTRAINT pk_CostID PRIMARY KEY (Year, Factory_Code, Month, Product)
CONSTRAINT FK_ Factory_Code FOREIGN KEY (Factory_Code)
REFERENCES Factory (Factory_Code)
)
```

Задача:

Для каждой фабрики из тех, у которых нет объёмов в 9 месяце 2015, запустить некую существующую процедуру Warning_Send (@Factory_Code). Т.е. процедура принимает как параметр код фабрики, а запустить её надо несколько раз – для каждой фабрики, подходящей под условие.

Мой код:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Warning_Send1

@Factory_Code char(4)

AS

IF @Factory_Code in 

(

SELECT Factory_Code

FROM Volume

WHERE Year<>2015

AND Month<>9

)

EXEC Warning_Send @Factory_Code

ELSE    

PRINT 'Не подходит под заданные условия'
```

Возможности проверить код нет, подскажите, пожалуйста, корректен ли он?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

> корректен ли он?

Нет, некорректен. Условие

```
WHERE Year<>2015 AND Month<>9
```

проверяет СУЩЕСТВОВАНИЕ объёмов хотя бы в одном, кроме сентября, месяце любого года, кроме 2015-го. Должно быть наоборот -

```
IF @Factory_Code NOT IN ( SELECT Factory_Code
                          FROM Volume
                          WHERE Year=2015
                          AND Month=9
                        )
```

Comment: Да, абсолютно согласен, это, скорее, опечатка. А если в целом оценивать синтаксис?